# How to Pass Variables from one Batch to Another

Tags: batch-file, variables, time, cmd

I have a bat script and I am trying to capture processing time of each functionality within it. I have two other bat scripts that capture the start time and end time but when I try to pass back those variables to the main script, it does not work. Please advise

> TRIGGER.bat

```
if exist "inProcess.lok". (
   exit
      ) else (
            if EXIST "some.ZIP". (
                call startTime.bat
                set /a startDel=%1

    ::some Process

                call endTime.bat
                set /a endDel=%2
                set /a timeDel= ( %endDel% - %startDel% )
                set /a timeDels= %timeDel% / 100
                set timeDel=%timeDels%.%timeDel:~-2%
                echo %timeDel%
                echo %timeDel%
                echo %timeDel%
                pause
    ))
```

> startTime.BAT

```
set starttime=%TIME%
set startcsec=%STARTTIME:~9,2%
set startsecs=%STARTTIME:~6,2%
set startmins=%STARTTIME:~3,2%
set starthour=%STARTTIME:~0,2%
set /a starttime=(%starthour%*60*60*100)+(%startmins%*60*100)+(%startsecs%*100)+(%startcsec%)

:trigger.bat %starttime%
```

> endTime.Bat

```
set endtime=%time%
set endcsec=%endTIME:~9,2%
set endsecs=%endTIME:~6,2%
set endmins=%endTIME:~3,2%
set endhour=%endTIME:~0,2%
if %endhour% LSS %starthour% set /a endhour+=24
set /a endtime=(%endhour%*60*60*100)+(%endmins%*60*100)+(%endsecs%*100)+(%endcsec%)

:trigger.bat %endtime%
```

Comment: Batch files all execute in the same process. You can just use the variable as set by previous batch files in the same process. If you pass the values via command-line arguments, then they don't have a name, but a number.

Comment: Gotcha, thing is I am using the passed variables as numbers  
set /a endDel=%2
set /a startDel=%1

but for some reason the script is not accepting these values.

Comment: You need to invoke `delayedexpansion` [hundreds of SO aricles about that - use the search feature] in order to display the run-time value of any variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block"). Why don't you do the calculation and display within `endtime.bat` where you could supply parameters to display say the name of the procedure that's ending?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Invoke delayedExpanion did not solve my problem. I will worry about the calculation and all later, but for now, the variables in endtime.bat aren't even getting passed to the trigger.bat

Answer (score 0):

you use `call`, labels and parameters in a random way. That won't work.
Here is a very basic example of how it could work (without parameters, just using variables, like Joey suggested in a comment)

Trigger.bat:

```
set starttime=dummy
set endtime=dummy
call starttime.bat
call endtime.bat
echo %starttime% %endtime%
```

starttime.bat:

```
set starttime=hello
```

endtime.bat:

```
set endtime=world
```